# Change URL argument separator

Tags: php, url, separator

First I have to say that I am a total newbie, I have literally 0 experience with PHP.

Here is my problem. I have a sensor, that sends data into mysql database in following form:

```
http://192.168.1.2/add.php?i=mit=0106,22:5113/07/2016,liv=175cm,livp=000%,b=12.0V,t=36;
```

Now I am able to display this in my mysql table:

```
"mit=0106,22:5113/07/2016,liv=175cm,livp=000%,b=12.0V,t=36;"
```

but I would like to display each argument separately.

Do you know how to change the separator from "&" to ","?

Ideal solution would be to change the url command to this form:

```
http://192.168.1.2/add.php?i=mit=0106&22:5113/07/2016&liv=175cm&livp=000%&b=12.0V&t=36;
```

but unfortunately I can reprogramm the sensor, so I need to change the separator from "&" to ",".

Comment: I'm not sure that just changing the separator will help. I assume that `add.php` looks for a variable `$_GET['i']` and writes that string to the database. Other variables in the URL will likely be ignored. I think you'll need to alter the PHP code to handle multiple variables from the URL, or at least to parse the `i` string into multiple values before database insertion.

Comment: it's just a string. if you want to replace characters in the string, then use `str_replace()`

Answer (score 4):

[`arg_separator.input`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.input) is the configuration directive you are looking for:

> arg_separator.input string
> List of separator(s) used by PHP to parse input URLs into variables.
>
> Note:
> Every character in this directive is considered as separator!

Be aware the setting mode is PHP_INI_PERDIR, meaning it "can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)" (http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)

---

If you can't change this setting, you might look at the query string as a whole (see $_SERVER variable), and split it at the comma yourself, using explode or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you have to store all `name=value` pairs from that string into separate columns in database table.

**In this case you can't use explode() because of first value that contains comma.**

Assuming that you already have created columns called `mit`, `liv`, `livp`, `b` and `t` with required data-type, and your string is double-checked before it goes to database to avoid SQL injections, you can do something like this:

```
# your input string
$input = "mit=0106,22:5113/07/2016,liv=175cm,livp=000%,b=12.0V,t=36;";

# loop through it and determine all name=value pairs
while (strlen($input)>2) {
    preg_match ('/([a-z]+)\=(.*?)(?:,[a-z]+=|;)/', $input, $m);
    # store names here
    $d1[] = "'{$m[1]}'";
    # and values here
    $d2[] = "'{$m[2]}'";
    $input = substr($input, strlen($m[1]) + strlen($m[2]) + 2);
}

# join arrays into string
$d1 = join(",", $d1);
$d2 = join(",", $d2);

# and put them into query
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable ($d1) VALUES ($d2);";

echo $sql;
```

This will print out a query like this

```
INSERT INTO mytable ('mit','liv','livp','b','t')
VALUES ('0106,22:5113/07/2016','175cm','000%','12.0V','36');
```

**How that `while` loop works?**

It uses `$input` as argument and look for `name=value` followed by another `name=` (for inner pairs) or `;` (for last pair) to determine its end. Than it extracts **name** into separate array `d1` and **value** into another array called `d2`. Removes first match from the beginning of the string and takes another turn in loop until the `$input` string is empty. Course, elements into those two arrays are stored surrounded with single quotes for later use in query.

At the end, I joined both arrays (separately) with comma between elements and put them into query string called `$sql`.

**Please note (again)** that it's dangerous to send data this way directly from URI's GET parameter into database with no previous validation of data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean exactly but you can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to help you or possibly you can convert this into an array using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) then do what you need to do with the data and put it back into a string using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

edit: thanks, fixed the mixup.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo "http://192.168.1.2/add.php?i=" . str_replace(",","&","mit=0106,22:5113/07/2016,liv=175cm,livp=000%,b=12.0V,t=36;");
```

Comment: Answers should have explanations about what you are doing and why. Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.